# Get values from Firebase real database to make a chart with them

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get values of sensors from Firebase and make a chart from that values. I wrote some code but it doesn't work. The graph should be automatically based on the values from the database, that is, there should be a complete synchronization of the graph with the values.
Here my db:

```
..sensor
-Lh51ca_FMrRMOA0Ok9B
hum: 36.1
pressure: 1008
temp: 31.2
time: "2019-06-11T13:17:03Z"
```

-and a lot of nodes

I using GraphView for making a chart

```
protected void onCreate(){
    ....
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot myDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                double temp = myDataSnapshot.child("temp").getValue(Double.class);
                double hum = myDataSnapshot.child("hum").getValue(Double.class);
                series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastXPoint, temp), false, 1000);
                series2.appendData(new DataPoint(lastXPoint, hum), false, 1000);
            }


        }
```

Only two points appeared on the graph and thats all.

Edit:

```
    protected void onCreate(){
        ....
        reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
                for(DataSnapshot myDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    lastXPoint +=0.1d;
                    double temp = myDataSnapshot.child("temp").getValue(Double.class);
                    double hum = myDataSnapshot.child("hum").getValue(Double.class);
                    series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastXPoint, temp), false, 1000);
                    series2.appendData(new DataPoint(lastXPoint, hum), false, 1000);
                }
            }
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) { }
        });
}
```

UPDATE. Now the chart is updated in real time. Seem to be it's works well

```
reference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
            lastXPoint +=0.1d;
            double temp = dataSnapshot.child("temp").getValue(Double.class);
            double hum = dataSnapshot.child("hum").getValue(Double.class);
            series.appendData(new DataPoint(lastXPoint, temp), false, 1000);
            series2.appendData(new DataPoint(lastXPoint, hum), false, 1000); 
            }
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) { }
        });
```

Comment: Plese add a more details database structure and indicate how is `reference` defined.

Comment: database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        reference = database.getReference("sensor");

Comment: If you add this line of code `Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(temp));` inside the for loop, how many results do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***lastXPoint*** variable seems to be constant within in the loop. So you append values to the same X point in the graph again and again through out the loop.

You have to vary the ***lastXPoint*** as well to draw a continuous graph with all the values in the DB nodes.

Edit: For duplicating value issue

addvalueeventlistner will bring all the nodes again again once the DB is updated. To bring the lastly added node only use below.

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("YOUR-URL-HERE/PATH/TO/YOUR/STUFF");

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousKey) {
    }
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    }
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    }
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) { }
});
```

Comment: If it solves your problem don't forget to mark this as the right answer.

Comment: oh, now i have another problem. Now all the values from the database are duplicated on the chart every time, and not just another new point is added

Comment: it works, but I want the chart to be updated in real time and I would not have to restart to the application.
Maybe update the chart  by pressing a button or maybe after a while?

Comment: Updated again. 'onChildAdded' method will serve for your purpose i guess.

Comment: Class 'Anonymous class derived from ChildEventListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onCancelled(DatabaseError)' in 'ChildEventListener'

Comment: public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) { }
so i changed that line and it works. I should write my previous code in onChildAdded method like?

Comment: Hope your problem is solved. If so mark this as the correct ans.

Comment: i have that error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference
at com.example.myapplication228.MainActivity$6.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:199)

Comment: Issue is onchildAdded() will only get the last child only. you for loop doesn't make any sense. dataSnapshot.getChildren() has no values. it is a single child value, not the all of them as in previous method

Comment: i updated my first message. So how to get only last child without a loop?

Comment: i see. it is tricky. Calling both methods might work. you have to try and see. Another way i can propose is that going back to valueeventlistner but with a local variable to keep the count of the data you recieved. So if the local count(X) is 0 you populate the graph with all the data, if not get the difference between local count and current DB count(Y) to get only the newly added nodes using limitToLast(Y-X) or something. Developing the trick is complete to up to you. Use your own logic.

Comment: Don't forget to update the post with method you chose and the result. It will help to some one as well